# How to give exe to testing for console application C#

Tags: c#, publish

In my console application(practiseprj), On post build events I generated exe files with 4 different names. Which creates exe in specified folder. I moved those exe to folder and tried to execute. It worked fine.

When I have any dependency like reading value from config then it not worked. This time  I moved `app.config` to respective folder and executed but it is not recognizing.

Now I renamed `app.config` to  `practiseprj.exe` and clicked in application file then it worked. But I feel renaming `app.config` is not correct.
My task is same code should work for 4 regions which varies based on key value in `app.config`. How these 4 exe and respective config need to b shared to testing team

Comment: iirc, the config file of a release exe should indeed be assemblyname.exe.config

Comment: dlatikay is right...i did one an hour ago

Comment: do we need to rename manually??..because in my scenario I have to give 4 exes and respective configs.. However my post build event command generating 4 exes(copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)\Executables\southregion.exe).. 
But I am renaming app.config as southregion.exe. If I give this to CA7 scheduler it will pick app.config I feel..Please help out. Thanks all for posting. Due to text limit din say thanx to JuanR

Answer (score 1):

You could use different build configurations (one for each region) as well as a Visual Studio extension to transform app.config files. See [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) or [Configuration Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform). You can then produce a build for each region with its own customized configuration file.

Generally speaking (off the top of my head):

- Install one of the recommended extensions.
- Go to the configuration manager .
- Create four different configurations, one for each region (e.g Region1, Region2, Region3, Region4).
- Create four different app.config files (e.g. app.Region1.config, app.Region2.config, app.Region3.config, app.Region4.config)
- Set the values on each file, as you need them. The app setting keys will have the same name.
- Go to Build > Batch Build
- Check the boxes for the four Region configurations.
- Hit the Build button.
- Grab the generated output from the bin\Region1, bin\Region2, bin\Region3, bin\Region4 folders. Each one will contain the binaries as well as the configuration file, properly named.

Comment: as per requirement region name I read from config. based on that switch case and logic varies. Key name is same value varies based on region. So I have 4 configs for 4 regions.I wrote a postbuild event copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)\Executables\newname.exe" this generating exe in Executables folder with the name 'newname'.This I am copying and moving to other location to give it to QA team.I need to give respective config as well.When I keep both exe n config in one folder it's not working.when I rename config it's working.How to give this to testing team.They need to test for 4 regions.

Comment: @San: I guess you do not understand my answer. I will update it with a bit more detail. Take another read.

Comment: @San: There, check the answer now. It has everything you need.